# How to prevent child component SVG fill color in parent SVG in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js

I have added D3 map as a child component to the parent. But when ever I am changing map background color using  **.attr('fill', '#00A3E0')**, parent component's SVG elements get the same color. I have tried all Angular way to prevent this. But unfortunately nothing is working for me

Setting ViewEncapsulation(Emulated or shadowDom) to child component didn't help for this scenario.

Child component:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
      .scale(700)
      .translate([this.width / 2, this.height / 2]);

    const path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection);

    const svg = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
      .attr('height', this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
      .attr('width', this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
      .style('cursor', 'pointer');

    const g = svg.append('g');

const loadmap = d3.json('assets/map/PTCH_ARA2.json')
      .then((topology) => {
        g.selectAll('path')
          .data(t.feature(topology, topology.objects.PTCH_ARA2).features)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', path)
          **.attr('fill', '#00A3E0')** 
          .attr('transform', 'scale(1.3)')
          .style('stroke', '#fff')
          .style('stroke-width', '1')
          .on('mouseover', this.mapMouseHover)
          .on('mouseout', this.mapMouseOut)
          .on('click', this.mapClick)
      });
}

HTML:

<div id="map" (mouseover)="onMouseOver($event)" (mouseout)="mouseOut($event)" tabindex="0" cdkScrollable></div>
```

Comment: So the parent contains multiple SVGs? What does `g` point to? Probably it points to the wrong (or all) SVGs

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Thanks. Yes parent having mat table and all material icon is SVG. I have updated my question. g = svg.append('g'); and svg = d3.select('#map').append('svg')

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the behaviour that you see, it's still unclear to me